# Search created_by_alias field in Joomla! content

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

Is there a module to extend the search engine in Joomla! to search also by author (created_by) and author alias (created_by_alias) in articles?

I was thinking make a simple pluging for this intention but first i simple tried modified the plugins/search/content.php file as follows:

```
case 'exact':
    $text           = $db->Quote( '%'.$db->getEscaped( $text, true ).'%', false );
    $wheres2        = array();
    $wheres2[]      = 'a.title LIKE '.$text;
    $wheres2[]      = 'a.introtext LIKE '.$text;
    $wheres2[]      = 'a.fulltext LIKE '.$text;
    $wheres2[]      = 'a.metakey LIKE '.$text;
    $wheres2[]      = 'a.metadesc LIKE '.$text;
    $wheres2[]      = 'a.created_by_alias LIKE '.$text; // added
    $where          = '(' . implode( ') OR (', $wheres2 ) . ')';
    break;

case 'all':
case 'any':
default:
    $words = explode( ' ', $text );
    $wheres = array();
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $word           = $db->Quote( '%'.$db->getEscaped( $word, true ).'%', false );
        $wheres2        = array();
        $wheres2[]      = 'a.title LIKE '.$word;
        $wheres2[]      = 'a.introtext LIKE '.$word;
        $wheres2[]      = 'a.fulltext LIKE '.$word;
        $wheres2[]      = 'a.metakey LIKE '.$word;
        $wheres2[]      = 'a.metadesc LIKE '.$word;
        $wheres2[]      = 'a.created_by_alias LIKE '.$word; // added
        $wheres[]       = implode( ' OR ', $wheres2 );
    }
    $where = '(' . implode( ($phrase == 'all' ? ') AND (' : ') OR ('), $wheres ) . ')';
    break;
```

in the **exact** and **default** cases but without luck. It does not return the results as expected when I search by an author alias. The fact is that it returns the same results.

Do I must modify other files?

Thanks in advance

PS: I'm using Joomla! 1.5

Comment: I'm sure you're probably doing this already - but as a safeguard, make sure you're using template overrides to achieve this and not modifying the core so in future upgrades your work won't get wiped out!  I know it's a little off topic - but figured the more information the better!  Regarding your topic specifically I'm afraid I don't have much in the way of helping, sorry!

Comment: @Hanny I've that in mind. I'm working now with a development server. So, I would like to know if that is possible before read about templates override. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting this in default case

$wheres2[]  = 'a.created_by_alias LIKE '.$word;

you have to do few more modifications..

at the end of the file it call as function checkNoHTML
look for line containing this 
    if(searchHelper::checkNoHTML($article, $searchText, array('text', 'title', 'metadesc', 'metakey')))

replace it by

```
if(searchHelper::checkNoHTML($article, $searchText, array('text', 'title', 'metadesc', 'metakey','created_by_alias')))   // just added created_by_alias in last array parameter
```

now in all the queries above add "a.created_by_alias"  in the select field list

Comment: i tried it and it works for me. can you please show your code.

Comment: Perfect :) I missed that part. Thanks!